# How to Run Plugin on Server Without Web Browser

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron, server

I have a function that requests product data from Amazon (`get_product_data()`) and would like to run this on my live site either on command or at regular intervals. To save the data into the database I need to use the Pods plugin.

I have thought of two ways to do this.

1. Run as a [wp cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/): The problem is the function takes several minutes to run and the unlucky visitor who loads the page and triggers the cron job will have to wait before seeing the page.
2. Use a normal cron job/run on the server somehow (?).

Ideally I want the 2nd way but how can I use the Pods plugin if it's a normal cron job? Is there some way to load WordPress in my server without a web browser (I'm using Siteground by the way)?

I'm relatively new so I appreciate all the help!

Comment: #1 is a misunderstanding. The cron job occurs in a separate request that’s fired in the background. The user doesn’t have to wait.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Oh that makes sense. I was confused because I was temporarily using the 'init' hook as a workaround to make the function run and in that case I had to wait several minutes to see my site.